# Gradle resolve compile and build dependencies

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

This is might be redundant question but I'm still unable to find the answer. The scenario is : I have 4 projects in my workspace say Project A, B ,C and D. Now the project B has a compile dependency on project A and once project B is built successfully i want to trigger the build for project C and D. Now in my **project B** settings.gradle file I have

```
include 'A'
include 'C'
project(':A').projectDir = file('../A')
project(':C').projectDir = file('../C')
project(':D').projectDir = file('../D')
```

Now the build.gradle for project B contains a block

```
    dependencies {
         compile project(:A)
    }
    build.doLast {
         subprojects.build
    }
```

When the subprojects are built it also builds the project A but i want to avoid that. I want to separate the compile dependencies (which can be more than one project) and the build dependencies. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the difference between a compile dependency and a build dependency?

Comment: @MichaelEaster by build dependency i mean the projects that should be built when the root project is built. Like in the above case trigger build for project C and D after project B is built.